# File content is empty while downloading from S3 bucket via API gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have a nodejs application deployed into aws lambda. There is a functionality to upload and download documents. When I try to download an already uploaded file, it is coming as blank. Upload code is as mentioned below.

```
const uploadToAWS = async (files) => {
   
    console.log('in upload to aws',files);
    const file = files[0];
    const uploadParams = {
        Bucket: 'claimplus-images',
        Key: `${new Date().toISOString()}_${file.originalname}`,
        Body: file.buffer
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(uploadParams, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error uploading files:', err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('file uploaded successfully');
                if (file.path) {
                    fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
                }
                resolve(uploadParams.Key); // Return the file's S3 URL
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Code for download is as below

```
exports.downloadImage = async (req, res) => {    
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'claimplus-images',
      Key: req.body.imagePath,
    };

    console.log('in download image function');

    const file = await s3.getObject(params).promise();


    const fileExtension = req.body.imagePath.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    const contentType = getContentType(fileExtension);
    const fileName = req.body.imagePath.split('/').pop();

    res.set('Content-Type', contentType);
    res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${fileName}.${fileExtension}"`);

      console.log('in download image function contentType',contentType);

    res.send(file.Body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
  };

  function getContentType(fileExtension) {
    switch (fileExtension) {
      case 'xlsx':
        return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
      case 'pdf':
        return 'application/pdf';
      default:
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }
  }
```

Serverless configuration is as mentioned below.

```
service: my-plus-api
frameworkVersion: '3'
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  httpApi:
    cors: true
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - "*/*"

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    name: my-plus-api
    events:
      - httpApi: "*"
```

I think the issue is with API gateway as Binary media types is not enabled. I have given it in the configuration but not sure it is correct or not.
I can't see this setting in API gateway screen also.

Please help

Comment: In the application where I work, we had this case. Also as API gateway have hard limit of 30 seconds to return the response, there was chance of download failure at client side where bandwidth is very low. 
We changed the architecture, where we attached lambda to API gateway which returns S3 presigned URL for short duration (1 minute) and then client calls that pre-signed URL which downloads the object from bucket.